# Appbar Transition Animation (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

I am beginner for Flutter App Development, I want to know how can I make a app like the UI like those pictures
[image]
[image]
I want to make a(an) UI which is when I scroll the page , the appbar can change itself color or change the contents.

Can someone let me know about what Widget I have to use or show the accurate step(codes) to do that?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about paralax behavior. Flutter already provides a widget for this.  You can use SliverAppbar.

[SliverAppBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)

SliverAppBar(
expandedHeight: 150.0,
flexibleSpace: const FlexibleSpaceBar(
title: Text('Available seats'),
),
actions: [
IconButton(
icon: const Icon(Icons.add_circle),
tooltip: 'Add new entry',
onPressed: () { /* ... */ },
),
]
)

Answer (score 0):

`SliverAppBar` is the way to go for that type of dynamic app bar, but in case anyone lands here and only needs a *fixed height* bar, you could use an `AnimatedSwitcher` for changing just individual components inside, or if its easier for you to rebuild a new `AppBar`, you can use this simple wrapper with a `builder` function return to the appropriate AppBar, while setting the `Scaffold`'s appBar field to an instance of this:

```
class AnimatedAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final Widget Function() builder;
  final Widget Function(Widget child, Animation<double> animation)?
      transitionBuilder;
  final double height;

  const AnimatedAppBar(
      {Key? key,
      required this.builder,
      this.transitionBuilder,
      this.height = kToolbarHeight})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AnimatedSwitcher(
      transitionBuilder:
          transitionBuilder ?? AnimatedSwitcher.defaultTransitionBuilder,
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      child: builder(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(height);
}
```

This still gives you a little flexibility in playing with the transition if you want something other than a cross-fade. E.g. you can also condition it on the child's `Key` inside the `transitionBuilder` you supply if needed.